# Left alignment seems to create additional spacing draft js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

[image]

When I click left alignment, extra spacing appears.

I'm using "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.4"

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore its `height` and set it to new value by setting the `height` property of class `.rdw-left-aligned-block` as `!important`.

```
.rdw-left-aligned-block {
    height : 2.2rem!important;
}
```